# Umbraco 7.2.8 - how do remove existing user/node permissions from code

Tags: umbraco7, user-permissions

I am trying to manage user permissions

I know that if I want to grant a particular user Publish and Browse (PermissionIds U,F) I would do this:

```
contentService.AssignContentPermission(node, 'U', userId);
contentService.AssignContentPermission(node, 'F', userId);
```

but if the user already had those permissions and I want to remove Publish and grant 'Send to Publish' (H) how do I remove the existing Publish permission for that user/node combo?

I tried:

```
contentService.AssignContentPermission(node, '-', userId);
```

but this didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like it's best to assign the permissions using the ApplicationContext.Current.Services.UserService

get all applicatble nodes (a single one in my case) and permissions and call

```
userService.ReplaceUserPermissions(user.Id, permissions, nodes);
```